# django: How can i assign email_token_expiry datetime to null?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

```
def confirmemail(request,token):

    user = Users.objects.get(email_token = token)
    if user:
        user.email_token = ''
        user.email_token_expiry = ''
        user.email_verified = 1
        user.active = 1
        user.save()
    return render_to_response('confirmemail.html', {'user': user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I get error:

```
ValidationError at /confirmemail/mw054b7el2/

[u'Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format.']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirmemail/mw054b7el2/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ValidationError
Exception Value:    

[u'Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format.']

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in to_python, line 710
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:    

['/home/user1/djangoblog',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
```

`email_token_expiry` is a `datetime` field in mysql table.

How can i set the `email_token_expiry` to null or empty or to the right formated null/0/empty datetime?

It will be highly appreciated if someone help me to fix this problem.

models.py:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    password_token = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='0')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField()
    tos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_action = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UsersModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.keyOrder = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'passwordrepeat']


    passwordrepeat = forms.CharField(max_length=300, widget=forms.PasswordInput, label=u'Repeat Password')

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'passwordrepeat', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'password' : forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        passwordrepeat = cleaned_data.get("passwordrepeat")
        if password != passwordrepeat:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match.")

        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: What does the `Users` model look like?

Comment: I added the `Users` model. See that again to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `email_token_expiry` as @ArthurNeves suggests in models.py.

```
email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Then when you set `email_token_expiry` it must be:

```
user.email_token_expiry = None
```

Not:

```
user.email_token_expiry = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what u need is set the token for a further data! try this out:

```
import datetime
user.email_token_expiry = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
```

**EDIT**

or if you want to set the data as blank|null u just have to modify your model field:

```
email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This will allow u to set as None or blank

more docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null

just one more think, after you change your model, dont forget to apply a migration, if you are using south, or drop the table and create it again if you dont have a migrate tool set!

**EDIT2**
Make sure to drop the table users and run syncdb right after. (if you dont have south set)
After that you can check your db to see if that field is nullable! issue a 'desc ..users' in your db so you can double check this.
If it is still not working

Comment: You misunderstood the problem. The token is set during registration. Now after confirming the email, i need to set this time to NULL or empty. What you posted was done in `def register(request):` method.

Comment: i have set `email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)`  Still the same error for this, `user.email_token_expiry = ''` ,

Comment: have u drop the table and run syncdb again??

Comment: Yes, i have dropped the table, then ran, `python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: check my second edit! if still doesnt work! drop all you db and create again then run syncdb!